# Comment box changes width of comment section

Tags: bug, comments, design

This is the comment thread:

> [image]

And this is the comment thread after I open the comment box, to add another one:

> [image]

Opening the comment box changes the width of something, which causes the text to move about. See the two over each other:

> [image]

This is happening on [elementary OS private beta](http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com), and reproduced on Code Golf beta site:

> [image]

Looking closely, the width of the `div class="comments"` is still 660px but the inner table is 100%. The `tfoot` is 673px.

Comment: Is this actually a "problem"? The definition of a "bug" (as I see it) is essentially "not by design *and* it's a problem". Is something a bug if it's  "not by design but works ok"? Or is it just "not by design"? Apart from "*Opening the comment box changes the width of something*" you haven't actually described any adverse effects from this.

Comment: @James well it bugs me...? It shouldn't do that - that section should be 660px not 673px.

Comment: A bug = bug report. It bugging "you" = feature request ;) (tho, I'm not saying this should be FR, I'm just not sure it's a bug)